# Query on generic usage in F#, specifically new T() and ref cells

Tags: generics, f#, mutable, ref

What would the F# equivalent of this bit of C#:

```
    public T GetNewItem()
    {
        return new T();
    }
```

In addition how would you return the ***new T()*** as a ref cell for usage in a .Net library requiring an out or ref parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think something as simple as this would work:

```
let getNewItem() = new 'T()
```

It infers the default constructor constraint.

```
let mutable d = getNewItem() //d inferred to be System.DateTime
DateTime.TryParse("1/1/2011", &d)
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, I think I was trying to make it too complicated.  What if I wanted to initialise it to null as you might in C# before using it as a ref parameter

Comment: I ended up with this as I didn't really need to construct it and didn't want to force the default constructor constraint:

let item = ref Unchecked.defaultof<'T>

Comment: +1, this is way cool, I didn't realize F# function type inference was *this* powerful. I remember when first learning F# being totally confused by implicit generic parameters introduced by '.

Comment: @Stephen - I'm often surprised by what the compiler infers. I've learned to start with the most minimal solution, then add information as-needed.